# drag and drop for html5 in NME project

Tags: haxe, nme

I am using ***haxe***, ***nme*** and ***flashdevelop***.

I am trying to convert a *flex* project to *html5*.

I have a few circles drawn by code on stage. In *as3* we can usually add ***individual eventlisteners*** to each of the objects (in *for* loop) and can use the ***startdrag***, ***stopdrag*** methods for dragging objects.

This works fine for the flash build.  But for the HTML5 build things are not working.

Seems the **EnterFrame** event is missing in other platforms, Hence the issue.

I also got the suggestion on web to use **Timer** class for the same, but I am not sure how can this be used to ***enable drag & drop*** on **multiple objects** for **html5** in **nme**. Below is the **Timer** code.

```
var timer = new Timer(10);  
timer.run = onEachTimerTick; 
function onEachTimerTick() { }
```

Please guide. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the great StableUI project, created by Alexander Kuzmenko.
https://github.com/RealyUniqueName/StablexUI

You can build complex interfaces (http://ui.stablex.ru/demo/demo_html5/) in a Flex-like way, using declarative xml.
Drag-and-drop support included: http://ui.stablex.ru/demo/dragDrop/

Jonas

Comment: Wow, this is awesome - I've been looking for something like it, could have made a project I just finished **much** easier. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, isn't it?! There's also Haxeui (https://github.com/ianharrigan/haxeui) - another new kid on the block. Not Html5-ready (yet!), but very nice for desktop-application look and feel.